# 'request.website_multilang' causes AttributeError in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I'm migrating Odoo module from version 10 to version 11. I have website template with following code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu js_language_selector" t-if="(request and request.website_multilang and len(languages) &gt; 1) or (website and (editable or translatable))">
```

It raises AttributeError: 'HttpRequest' object has no attribute 'website_multilang'. I can't find documentation on how to adapt this Odoo 10 code to v11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu js_language_selector" t-if="(request and request.is_frontend_multilang and len(languages) &gt; 1) or (website and (editable or translatable))">
```

I have just analysed that in v11 it needs to be "is_frontend_multilang" instead of "website_multilang".

Hope it works.

Regards

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Could you also, please, tell where you found that info

Comment: Thanks @Tchi-Odoo